# Custom Progress Bar with YouTube API

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbfxgxac/20/

(My code had to be in the HTML section or else it wouldn't work correctly)

I'm working on a video player for my website and I have it almost all working except for getting the progress bar to update as the video plays. Right now I was just testing with a button to run this code which updates the bar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //set vairables
    var curtime;
    var durtime;
    //set progressbar
    $("#prog").progressbar({
        max: durtime,
        value: curtime
    });
});

function updprog() {
    //Set variables
    curtime = player.getCurrentTime();
    durtime = player.getDuration();
    $( "#prog" ).progressbar({
        value: (curtime / durtime) * 100
    });
}
```

I can't find out how to make it run every half second or so when the YouTube player is playing. If I put it in a while loop then I can't click on any other buttons to stop the video or anything because my JQuery is running a loop.

This is my YouTube code so far:

```
     //asynchronously load youtube api script
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        //insert our youtube script before first script tag dynamically
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;

        //youtube function - onYouTubeIframAPIReady
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '432',
                width: '730',
                videoId: 'tYXftk1tJzw',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        //When youtube player is ready
        function onPlayerReady(e) {
            //e.target.playVideo(); //will make it play automatically
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
        }
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or something similar that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Added JSFilddle almost coulnd't get it to work in there

Comment: Where is the progress bar supposed to be showing, exactly?

Comment: You could also try checking out nprogress: http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/